# Read jsonFile to map

Tags: json, flutter, io

I want get json file on ftp server and convert this in map to use the objects.
I can do this.

```
Map myMap = new Map();
http
    .get('link.com')
    .then((response) =>{
      myMap = json.decode(Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes))})
    .whenComplete(() => {
          myMap.forEach((key, value) {
            setState(() {
              print(value);
            });
          })
        });
```

But I want to write the map to a file in my application folder and read the locally stored file.

but when I'm trying with my model file I can't because I have

```
{name: [{title: title, content: content}]}
```

and not

```
"name": [{"title": "title","content":"content"}]}
```

So I can't create a Map from the string.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Please add the code you are using to write the map to the local file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the file using `myMap.toString()` use `json.encode` to encode the map to a valid json string and save that that way you can decode it again when reading the file.